# IF statement in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Detail]   
      @ReceiptNumber int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;   

    WITH invoiceT AS 
    (SELECT 
       fs_transaksie.enti AS Entity,
       fs_transaksie.rek AS Account,
       fs_transaksie.trans_tipe AS TransactionType,
       fs_transaksie.verwysnr AS ReferenceNumber    
    FROM mf_history.dbo.fs_transaksie      
    WHERE ( fs_transaksie.verwysnr = @ReceiptNumber ) AND (fs_transaksie.trans_tipe = 3))
 , transactionT as
    (SELECT  
       fs_kwitansie.kwitansienr AS InvoiceNumber,
       fs_kwitansie.ktkaart_nr AS CreditCardNumber,
       fs_kwitansie.ktkaart_bank AS CCBank,
       fs_kwitansie.ktkaart_bedrag AS CCAmount    
    FROM mf_history.dbo.fs_kwitansie     
    WHERE ( fs_kwitansie.kwitansienr = @ReceiptNumber ) 
)
select * 
from invoiceT 
full outer join transactionT on invoiceT.ReferenceNumber = transactionT.InvoiceNumber  
END
```

If the fs_transaksie.trans_tipe field = 3 and fs_transaksie.rek = 5205 then an error message needs to be displayed to the user. He may NOT view the data

Comment: Does it need to be an error message or can you just not display the data?

Comment: @Thando Tee - In what field do you want to display the Error?

Comment: You can write a WHERE clause 'TransactionType!=3 OR Account!=5205'

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can just not display the data, rather than raising an error then changing your `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE ( fs_transaksie.verwysnr = @ReceiptNumber ) AND (fs_transaksie.trans_tipe = 3)
    And (fs_transaksie.rek != 5205)
```

should exclude it - you are already filtering it to just be `trans_tipe = 3` so adding the `And (fs_transaksie.rek != 5205)` will exclude any where the results are 3 **and** 5205 respectively.